# About Mercurial, .hgignore file and glob syntax

Tags: regex, syntax, mercurial, glob, hgignore

Is it possible, while using **glob** syntax for an .hgignore file, to recursively ignore certain files and folders, except one?

Assuming that you have:

```
a/
a/b
a/c
a/d
```

Something like:

```
syntax globe:
a
^a/b
```

This should ideally ignore **c** and **d** and keep **b**.

I know this has been discussed in other SO questions, but it seems they're all using **regex** mode for the syntax.

Comment: Why can't you use the regex syntax? It would be much easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The glob syntax is transformed to regex in [match.py](http://selenic.com/repo/hg/file/cc9f16a1f545/mercurial/match.py). It seems that this is the syntax you are looking for:

```
syntax:glob

a/*[!b]
```

Comment: This works fin in this example, but apparently not with nested subfolders (in my real repo, I need to skip something like a/*[!b/sub/subsub]). I tried to escape the slashes in several modes, but it didn't help. Any suggestion?

Comment: Accepted as best answer so far :)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to ignore all but one, just add that one.  Adding a file overrides ignoring it, which differs from subversion or cvs, but is incredibly handy.

Comment: I would prefer to avoid this procedure. It's error prone and I usually forget adding files to hg after creating a lot of them :)

Comment: @Roberto Aloi than all executables and other generated stuff would clutter your commits. I'd rather add new files, than removing all unneeded stuff every time.